# Agregar simbolo porcentaje en JTextField

Tags: java, jtextfield, numberformat

Estoy tratando de agregar el símbolo de porcentaje a un textfield. Pero por ejemplo si el valor que ingrese es 25 me lo pasa a miles y queda como 2.500%
Lo estoy intentando mostrar en el JTextField con: **op.intGanancia** pero tambien al imprimirlo en consola con system.out.print me lo muestra como en miles.

La intención es que al presionar enter, salte al siguiente textfield. Y en el que se escribe el porcentaje que desea ganar, quede con el valor que ingreso previamente y el simbolo % al final.

Código:

```
    public class mate {

    String valoCompra = valorCompra.getText();
    String porGanancia = porcentajeGanancia.getText();

    Double doCompra = Double.parseDouble(valoCompra);
    Double doGanancia = Double.parseDouble(porGanancia);
    int intGanancia = Integer.parseInt(porGanancia);
    
    Double operacion = ((doCompra * doGanancia) / 100) + (doCompra);
}
private void porcentajeGananciaKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                              
    if (evt.getKeyCode() == com.sun.glass.events.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        mate op = new mate();
        this.valorVenta.setText(op.operacion.toString());
        this.valorVenta.requestFocus();
        //formato %
        NumberFormat formatoPorciento = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        formatoPorciento.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        //formato %
        //cambio el JTextField agregando el % al valor.
        this.porcentajeGanancia.setText(formatoPorciento.format(op.intGanancia));
        //imprimo en la consola
        System.out.println("formatoPorciento = " + formatoPorciento.format(op.intGanancia));
        System.out.println("Int ganancia = " + op.intGanancia);
        System.out.println("porGanancia = " + op.porGanancia);
    }
}
```

Imagen de como actuá:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**NumberFormat.getPercentInstance()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getPercentInstance()) devuelve la representación porcentual del número *dato x 100.0* ,osea si pasas 25 aplicado el método en mención sera `25*100.0 =2500%` dicho ello podrías usar la variable `intGanancia` para obtener una representación decimal de 25 obteniendo 0.25 ,al aplicarse `getPercentInstance()`, sera `0.25*100.0` devolverá 25%

```
double intGanancia =doGanancia/100.0;//0.25
NumberFormat formatoPorciento = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
System.out.println("formatoPorciento = " + formatoPorciento.format(intGanancia));//25%
```

Comment: Hola Dramaturgo. Muchas gracias, la verdad te soy sincero, no entendí como ese simple cambio me anula los ceros 0 extra que se agregaban a mi resultado de porcentaje. Pero lo aplique y me quedo funcionando. Eternamente agradecido. La marque como correcta a la respuesta. Saludos.!

Comment: detalle un poco mas la respuesta,espero este mas claro,saludos ;)

Comment: Gracias Dramaturgo, tuve que agarrar la calculadora, y ver porque lo fraccionaba, claro es un paso esencial para que pueda usar el getPercentInstance. Muchas gracias.